# Getting "[archiver] unsupported version (1.12) in file header" when running pg_restore

Tags: postgresql

i have backup for pgrestore sql database 9.5 and i need restore it on 8.4 v but this error.
any idea to slove it

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aF5Fv.jpg)

Comment: Please don't post text as images.

Comment: 1) Both 9.5 and 8.4  are EOL, 1.5 and 8 years respectively. 2) You are having a version issue with the backup file. You will need to use the 9.5 version of `pg_restore` to restore to the 8.4 Postgres instance.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you were too sloven in your upgrading if you ask a question about these versions...

Anyway, `pg_restore` will flat out refuse to restore a dump created with a later version of `pg_dump`, and `pg_dump` will refuse to dump a database that has a more recent versions than itself. In short, you cannot downgrade with `pg_restore`, because downgrading is not supported in PostgreSQL.

Your only option is to create a plain format dump and restore it with `psql`. That will probably cause errors, and you will have to manually modify the dump file until it restores correctly.